# Is there a single word that can refer to both listeners or readers?

Tags: single-word-requests

Additionally, is there a counterpart that can refer to both the speaker or writer?

Example:

> The speaker/writer should use questions to elicit a response from the listener/reader.

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: Hopefully the question is clearer now.

Comment: Can you use *audience* for both listeners and readers?

Comment: Audience is a great answer! It is closer to listener since it has 'audio' as root, though.

Comment: A *speaker* can refer to someone who speaks words that someone else has written. It’s not an exact parallel with *writer*. This makes it hard to find a good answer to this question.

Comment: @GlobalCharm are you sure? Can you find any instance of such an acceptation?

Answer (score 1):

One pair of terms that covers *speakers/writers* and *listeners/readers* is **producers** and **receivers**. See the extract below from the Wikipedia article on [text linguistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_linguistics). *Text* in this context refers to both written and spoken language.

> Text **producers** often speculate on the **receiver**'s attitude of
>   acceptability and present texts that maximize the probability that the
>   **receivers** will respond as desired by the **producers**.

An alternative pair listed under the entry on *Communication* in the *Longman Dictionary of Language Teaching and Applied Linguistics* (p97) is **sender** / **receiver**:

> In an act of communication there is usually at least one speaker or
>   **sender**, a message which is transmitted, and a person or persons for whom this message is intended (the **receiver**).

Comment: I did think of sender and receiver (of messages), but I found it too generic, it can apply to much more than messages.

Never heard of text producer before.